# PayPal API: response says that my JSON request is malformed when revising my subscription

Tags: json, google-apps-script, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to change a customer plan from "pro" to "expert".

I am currrently operating on the live PayPal API.

However, when I try to change it using the following code (written in .gs):

```
var url = "https://api.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/" + subID + "/revise";
var bearer = "XXXXXXXXX";
var options = {
      "method": "POST",
      "contentType": "application/json",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + bearer
      },
      "payload": JSON.stringify({
        "plan_id": "X-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      })
    };
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
Logger.log(response);
```

I get as a response:

```
 {"name":"INVALID_REQUEST","message":"Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.","debug_id":"7df737cb91cff","details":[{"location":"body","issue":"MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON","description":"The request JSON is not well formed."}],"links":[]}
```

From the PayPal Developer API section:

```
curl -v -X POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-BW452GLLEP1G/revise  
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>" \
-d '{
  "plan_id": "P-5ML4271244454362WXNWU5NQ"
}'
```

Everything seems right, why is it not working?

**Note:**
I had the same response when canceling a subscription and I solved it adding the `JSON.stringify` to the payload. But in this case, even if I add it, it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Is this sandbox or live? Subscriptions and Plan IDs only exist in one environment or the other, you cannot mix the two. Update your question with the entire API response

Comment: @PrestonPHX Updated. I am working on live. Added the full response too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var url = "https://api.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/" + subID + "/revise";
```

Log this, you will likely find that subID is undefined

Comment: You are right. subID was undefined. Thank you!

Comment: No need to reproduce, it is now working, sorry for the confusion.